# Get list of all currently deployed versions on GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine

As I see I can get ID for current app only, for current request:

```
String versionId = ApiProxy.Environment.getCurrentEnvironment().getVersionId()
```

Is there any way of getting list of all deployed versions fo current application? Like a list at a Versions page of GAE Admin Dashboard.

PS Maybe it's possible to do by calling `appcfg.sh`? but I don't see such option there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The App Engine Admin API, currently in Trusted Tester phase, allows this:
https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/appengine/v1beta/

If you're interested, here is the [signup form](https://docs.google.com/a/google.com/spreadsheet/viewform?formkey=dFpXdHhLcW5vMVhtRktnOHZ2SWxMNmc6MQ#gid=0).

Comment: Igor, I probably should add a cautionary note -- you should take care using TT stage APIs in production apps (as the APIs might be changed, may be less stable, etc.)

Comment: Yes, I understand. It's for a local tool actually (a log analyser), so it's ok